# On heroku app not working code=H10

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I am getting this error on Heroku:

> 2018-07-09T04:37:55.732211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newcri.herokuapp.com request_id=b04ee149-4ed1-442f-beb1-4b71c9fd492f fwd="49.34.129.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Project url is https://github.com/ravikkanani/newapi

Comment: Please send the result of "heroku logs" command to give us more information about the issue.

Comment: This is solve by scalling my app thanks for support me